hexapod control in gazebo
I'm working on a 6-legged hexapod robot simulation in ROS 2 and Gazebo, and I'm struggling to create a realistic walking sequence. Here are the specifics of my project:
Current Setup:
ROS 2 Humble
Hexapod URDF already created
Gazebo launch file working
Basic robot model spawns successfully
What I'm Trying to Achieve: I want to implement a walking gait for my hexapod robot. Specifically, I'm looking for guidance on:
ROS 2 specific methods to control leg movements
What's the recommended approach to create walking sequences in ROS 2?
What controllers or packages are best for hexapod locomotion?
Seeking:
Code examples
Architectural guidance
Best practices for hexapod locomotion in ROS 2
